# Why do Entity Framework queries not return unsaved entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Consider the following code:

```
var Products_First = (from Entities.Product p in myContext.Product  
                      select p);

Entities.Product newProduct = new Entities.Product();
newProduct.Name = "New Product";
myContext.Products.AddObject(newProduct);

var Products_Again = (from Entities.Product p in myContext.Product  
                      select p);
```

Notice here that `Products_Again` is queried without saving the context, that is `myContext.SaveChanges()` is not called.

`Products_Again` contains the same number of products as `Products_First`. Why is this? A new `Product` is added and tracked by the same context object. Why can not I see the new product in the new query results?

After adding new object to the context is there a way to reach the new object without saving changes?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Properties of type `ObjectQuery<T>`, like `myContext.Product`, *always* query the DB. That's what they do.

In EF 4.1 you can use `DbSet<T>.Local` to query memory.

In EF < 4.1 you would use:

```
ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Select(o => o.Entity).OfType<Product>()
```

Comment: So, to get a results set with elements from both DB and memory I should keep a separate list of my own and try to keep it up to date. Is is the proposed solution for EF 4.0?

Comment: I don't understand your question -- I gave you a solution for EF 4.0 / EF 1.

Comment: It worked, but the <4.1 solution should include `Select(o=>o.Entity)`: `ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).Select(o=>o.Entity).OfType<Product>()`