# C# Entity Framework: Add/Insert record and select him without savechanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework in version 6.2.0.
And I have a simple question about this framework.
Is it possible to insert/add record, and select this same record before using `SaveChanges` function??

I'll try to represent this by simple code:

```
// prepare and add new record
User u = new User();
Context.Users.Add(u);
Context.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Added;

var y = (from x in Context.Users).FirstOrDefault(); // return null
// i expected that, in here i found new Created User 

Context.SaveChanges();

var y = (from x in Context.Ussers).FirstOrDefault(); // return != null
```

I'm doing this, because i'm going to join a created record with a few other tables.

Comment: This answer has options depending on what EF version you're on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6426326/84206

Answer (score 0):

DbSet has a `Local` property that represents a local view of the set (including `Added`, `Unchanged` and `Modified` entities). You can see [Entity Framework Local Data documentation](http://DbSet%20has%20a%20Local%20property%20that%20represents%20a%20local%20view%20of%20the%20set%20(including%20Added,%20Unchanged%20and%20Modified%20entities).%20See%20msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592872(v=vs.113).aspx) for more information.